# Android system service cannot access user data

Tags: android, android-service

I'm writing an Android system service under platform/frameworks/base, it is launched by SystemServer and runs as a system service like Activity Manager and Content Manager. The service can access and modify files created by user `system` successfully, for example, */data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db*.

However the service is not able to access data file owned by user applications. For example, */data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db* is owned by the user `app_7`, when trying to change the file, it throws a FileNotFoundException. I'm wondering why a system service cannot modify user data, or is it possible to do so?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the system service runs as a non-superuser account. This is generally a good thing from a security standpoint.

If you want to access contacts, you can try to do so like any other SDK application, via the `ContactsContract` content provider.

Comment: The contacts2.db is just an example, I have to deal with many other files created by the user application, is there any way to do this?

Comment: @ZelluX: You are creating custom firmware. StackOverflow historically has not been a good resource for this. http://source.android.com has links to Google Groups that may prove more useful.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll check that